# Svn how to archive old tags in a new directory

Tags: svn, tags

Within my SVN repo I want to move a large amount of tags into another root of my repo.
The current 'tags' dir is too crowded and it is a pain to pick the right one when needed.

How can I batch move all of them into a new 'archived_tags' dir of my repo.

I was not able to find any tips from google because my search returned doc about moving the tag from version 1 to version 2 or about relcating the repo to another repo, not to relocate the snapshots.

I'm using tortoise but I'll be glad to have a command to perform this action too.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the regular *move* operation to move tags from one directory to another directory. Using the command line client somewhere in the working directory, this looks as follows:

```
svn mkdir ^/old-tags
svn mv ^/tags/foo ^/tags/bar ^/tags/baz ^/old-tags
```

If you have a huge number of tags, and want to filter them automatically, then build the command line based on the output of `svn ls ^/tags`. Here is an example how this might look with bash:

```
svn mv $( svn ls ^/tags | sed -ne '/^ba.*$/s//^\/tags\/&/p' ) ^/old-tags/
```